# How to resolve this overlap div issue and understanding the concept?

Tags: html, css, position

I have show in attached diagram detail with problem i hope this will make clear sense and i got reply from professionals soon.

picture shown here due to some post restriction i am unable to upload or `embed picture` so you just need copy following url to understand problem.

***[image link here](http://oi50.tinypic.com/2r6o088.jpg)***

[image]

Thank You

Comment: let me know your order is like header, div1, div2, div3, footer.

Comment: try using: `#container{ overflow:auto }`

Comment: +1 for the graphic. Also, you may want to [create a jsfiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/). It makes working with such problems as yours much easier.

Answer (score 0):

I don't known your full code. In my point of view delete this two line and check.

```
footer{
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
}
```

The footer is must after the div3.

Comment: i remove these two line from css it works but when there is not dynamic page called in container area footer comes up on page some where center and it won't stick as i want it to stick bottom.

Comment: check the order as header, div,1,2,3 and footer.

Comment: i checked order is fine i tried many things but i think .push will work i will update code soon if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding this code before footer div.

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Comment: none of these work for me i already tried all these thing i want to clear one thing more that this is asp.net page and there is one master page where header container and footer are placed and in container dynamic page load if there is no data comes in dynamic page footer works fine.